Barba.js reload / init a script in a specific page
I have a base transition with gsap nothing too fancy and in the contact page a script to load a multistep form. I can't get barba to reload that script in that specific namespace 'contacto'. Anyone with any updated solutions? I've tried using views and hooks but nothing seems to be working. 
TLDR: reload script everytime barba transitions to a this specific page. 
Additional context: Low js knowledge and mostly use chatgpt. the code below is just one of several I have tried. (Probably tried 15+ different options and nothing yield results).
<script>
barba.init({
    views: [{
        namespace: 'contacto', 
        enter(data) {
            // Function to load the multi-step script
            loadMultiStepScript();
        },
        afterLeave(data) {
           
        }
    }],
    transitions: [{
        name: 'overlay-transition',
        leave(data) {
            const done = this.async();
            // Ensure that .transition is visible and ready for animation
            gsap.set('.transition', { display: 'block', opacity: 1, y: '100%' });
            gsap.to('.transition', {
                y: '0%',
                duration: 0.7,
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                onComplete: done
            });
        },
        enter(data) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            resetWebflow(data);
            gsap.set(data.next.container, { opacity: 0 });
            gsap.to(data.next.container, {
                opacity: 1,
                duration: 0.7,
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                delay: 0.2
            });
            gsap.to('.transition', {
                y: '-100%',
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: 'power2.inOut',
                delay: 0.2,
                onComplete: () => {
                    gsap.set('.transition', { display: 'none' });
                }
            });
        }
    }]
});

function loadMultiStepScript() {
    const scriptId = 'multi-step-script';
    // Remove any existing script instance
    const existingScript = document.getElementById(scriptId);
    if (existingScript) {
        existingScript.remove();
    }
    // Create and append a new script element
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = scriptId;
    script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/videsigns/webflow-tools@latest/multi-step.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function resetWebflow(data) {
    if (data) {
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let dom = parser.parseFromString(data.next.html, "text/html");
        let webflowPageId = $(dom).find("html").attr("data-wf-page");
        $("html").attr("data-wf-page", webflowPageId);
    }
    window.Webflow && window.Webflow.destroy();
    window.Webflow && window.Webflow.ready();
    window.Webflow && window.Webflow.require("ix2").init();
}
</script>

I have checked on barba docs for hooks and views but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

Have you tried putting your function call within a conditional that checks the namespace upon view enter? if (data.next.namespace == 'contacto') { loadMultiStepScript(); }

unfortunately it did not work :(

On your views -> enter(data) try console logging the data item. What does it log when visiting the contact page?

Does Webflow affect the barba hooks? Someone mentioned that I won't be able to reinit via barba hook on page transition if I am using webflow since it inits several stuff in the global scope.
